# python handling incoming from url

Tags: python, python-2.7

i'm sending below request to URL and get the response from it

```
import requests

url = "http://localhost/dat.txt"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36',
  'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Below is the response data that I get -

```
mohame4|nameon@example.com|passsd!@#$4|head,customer|manager,devlop
mohame3|nameon3@example.com|passsd!@#$4|head,customer|manager,devlop
```

I do this with the data

```
for i in response.text:
 try:
     i = i.strip().split('|')
     userna = i[0]
     emaill = i[1]
     passd = i[2]
     rol1= i[3]
     rol2= i[4]
 except:
     pass
```

How can I make rol1 as

```
this head,customer
```

to

```
 rol1=['head','customer']
```

Comment: Are you not getting your desired output? What are you getting?

Comment: What is your question? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it meant to provide personalized guides and tutorials. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `split` the string you're getting:

```
rol1 = i[3].split(',')
```

You could do this more... gracefully, though, using iterable unpacking:

```
username, email, password, rol1, rol2 = i.strip().split('|')
rol1 = rol1.split(',')
```

Comment: this is not what i need

Comment: What do you need, then? Your question seems to be about converting the string `'head,customer'` to the list `['head','customer']`, and `split` does exactly that

Comment: not to split it to make it like ['head','customer']

Comment: I mean, `i[3].split(',') == ['head','customer']`, so I don't see any issues here.

Comment: dat = str(response.text).split('\n')
for i in dat:
    i = i.strip().split('|')
    print(i[0])

Comment: @hamedalholi, wait, are you not able to loop over the individual lines at all? You should loop over `response.text.encode().splitlines()` then, instead of just `response.text`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all helper special @ForceBru

```
import requests

url = "http://localhost/dat.txt"


response = requests.request("GET", url)

print(response.text)
dat = str(response.text).split('\n')
for i in dat:
    i = i.strip().split('|')
    print(i[3].split(","))
    # TODO: write code...
```

Comment: How is this answer different from the answer given by ForceBru?